# Select rows based on total percentage of records present MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if I have put the right title, will be happy for the moderator to change it. Here is what i want:
Lets say i have a table with 3 columns

```
Id |   Name      |    campaignid
-----------------------------
1. |    John.    |     1
----------------------------
2  |    Peter.   |     2
---------------------------
3. |    Martin.  |     3
----------------------------
4. |    Sarah.   |     2
----------------------------
5. |    Jessica. |     3
----------------------------
6. |    Parker.  |     3
```

Now in reality i will have a million of records with approximately 1000 different campaignid, at a time i can only process 3000 records, so i want to select 3000 records and process them, then get another 3000 records and process them, so on and so forth. 
When i select 3000 records from the database I want to get the rows based on the percentage of campaignids present in total records. For ex in the above example, campaignid 3 is present 50%, 2 is 33.33% and 1 is 17.77%. Now if this was also the compisition of a million of records and i had to select 3000 records out of it, then campaignid 3 should be 1500 times, campaign id 2 should be 999 times and remaining should be campaign id 1, i.e. 50%, 33.3% and 17% respectively.

Please could anyone help me out with an efficient query for this. I am using Mysql database.

Comment: Please mark my answer below as accepted if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try MySQL's [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function. For example:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first SELECT would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT clause.